# php append on a specific line

Tags: php, append

The following script append the code at the end of the same file

```
$path = "./files/";
$path2="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/files/";
//echo $path2;
$folder = opendir($path);
$start="<asx version='3.0'>\n<title>Example ASX playlist</title>";
$Fnm = "./playlist.php";
// build content
$fileContent=$start.'/n';

while( $file = readdir($folder) ) {
 if (($file != '.')&&($file != '..')&&($file != 'index.htm')){
 $result="<entry>\n<title>$file</title>\n<ref href='$path2$file'/>\n<param name='image'        value='preview.jpg'/>\n</entry>\n";
 //append to content
$fileContent .= $result;
}
}
 //append to content
$fileContent .= "</asx>";

// append to file and check status
if ( file_put_contents(__FILE__ , $fileContent , FILE_APPEND) === false )
{

echo "failed to put contents in ".__FILE__."<br>";

}
```

I want to append this to a specific line for example at line 12

The result of this append is as follows

```
{
levels: [
{ file: "/bkaovAYt-3647661.mp4" },
{ file: "/bkaovAYt-3647661.mp4" }
],
title: "bkaovAYt-3647661.mp4"
},
```

is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place that second set of code in a file, say, `include.php` and then use the following code to place it wherever you want in the main PHP code:

```
include("include.php");
```

Comment: Can I use this include between javascript ?

Example between <script type="text/javascript"> </script>

Comment: Of course. It literally drops that code in where the `include()` is.